# Numpy multi-dimensional index

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, indexing, tensor

I have two numpy arrays - arr1 and arr2. arr2 contains index values for arr1. The shape of arr1 is (100, 8, 96, 192) and the shape of arr2 is (8, 96, 192). What I would like do is index arr1 with arr2, then get the 20 points after that as well.

For context, arr1 is time x model x lat x lon and all the indexes values in arr2 correspond to a point in time in the arr1 array. I would like to get the arr1 values at the point in time in arr2 and then twenty points after that.

Sample Data

```
arr1 = np.random.rand(*(100, 8, 96, 192))
arr2 = np.random.randint(low=0, high=80,size=(8, 96, 192))
```

```
in: print(arr1)

out: array([[[[0.61718651, 0.24426295, 0.9165573 , ..., 0.24155022,
          0.22327592, 0.9533857 ],
         [0.21922781, 0.87948651, 0.926359  , ..., 0.64281931,
         ...,
         [0.09342961, 0.29533331, 0.11398662, ..., 0.36239606,
          0.40228814, 0.87284515]]]])
```

```
in: print(arr2)

out: array([[[22,  5, 64, ...,  0, 37,  6],
        [71, 48, 33, ...,  8, 38, 32],
        [15, 41, 61, ..., 56, 32, 48],
        ...,
        ...,
        [66, 31, 32, ...,  0, 10,  6],
        [ 9, 28, 72, ..., 71, 29, 34],
        [65, 22, 50, ..., 58, 49, 35]]])
```

Comment: So the values of `arr2` are in the 0-100 range, possible indices of the first dimension of `arr1`?

Comment: Yes, they are in the range of the time dimension (0-th dimension of arr1). Although, since I need 20 points, they are in the range 0-80. I just added some sample data showing this.

Comment: `arr1[ arr2, I, J, K]` where `I, J, K = np.ix_(np.arange(8), np.arange(96), np.arange(192))`

Comment: Thanks, this definitely works (not entirely sure how just yet). 

For completion, if anyone wants this in the future as well, I did add that I needed the 20-points after that as well. I have solved this using
`np.array([arr1[arr2+i, I, J, K] for i in range(20]).mean(axis=0)`

Thank again :)

Comment: In `advanced indexing`, the index arrays are `broadcast` against each other.  Your `arr2` is (8,96,192).  Arrays produced by `ix_` (or `indexing`, or `meshgrid`) should be compatible, eg. (8,1,1), (1,96,1), and (1,1,192).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extrapolating from the comments; you can do this in one single operation with a mix of [advanced indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing) and [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

```
import numpy as np

arr1 = np.random.rand(100, 8, 96, 192)
arr2 = np.random.randint(low=0, high=80, size=(8, 96, 192))

H, I, J, K = np.indices((20, 8, 96, 192), sparse=True)

out = arr1[H + arr2, I, J, K].mean(axis=0)
```