# Numpy set all values to np.nan after index in multi-dimensional array

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, tensor, multi-index

I have two numpy arrays - arr1 and arr2. arr2 contains index values for arr1. The shape of arr1 is (100, 8, 96, 192) and the shape of arr2 is (8, 96, 192). What I would like do is set all of the values in arr1 to np.nan after the index values in arr2.

For context, arr1 is time x model x lat x lon and all the indexes values in arr2 correspond to a point in time in the arr1 array. I would like to set the arr1 values at after the point in time in arr2 to np.nan.

Sample Data

```
arr1 = np.random.rand(*(100, 8, 96, 192))
arr2 = np.random.randint(low=0, high=80,size=(8, 96, 192))
```

```
in: print(arr1)

out: array([[[[0.61718651, 0.24426295, 0.9165573 , ..., 0.24155022,
          0.22327592, 0.9533857 ],
         [0.21922781, 0.87948651, 0.926359  , ..., 0.64281931,
         ...,
         [0.09342961, 0.29533331, 0.11398662, ..., 0.36239606,
          0.40228814, 0.87284515]]]])
```

```
in: print(arr2)

out: array([[[22,  5, 64, ...,  0, 37,  6],
        [71, 48, 33, ...,  8, 38, 32],
        [15, 41, 61, ..., 56, 32, 48],
        ...,
        ...,
        [66, 31, 32, ...,  0, 10,  6],
        [ 9, 28, 72, ..., 71, 29, 34],
        [65, 22, 50, ..., 58, 49, 35]]])
```

For reference I have previously asked this question which had some similarities.
[Numpy multi-dimensional index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75954978/numpy-multi-dimensional-index)

Based upon this, I tried

```
arr1 = np.random.rand(100, 8, 96, 192)
arr2 = np.random.randint(low=0, high=80, size=(8, 96, 192))
I, J, K = np.indices((8, 96, 192), sparse=True)
out = arr1[arr2:, I, J, K]


TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

Also, perhaps similar to this in concept, but for much higher dimensional arrays
[Set values in numpy array to NaN by index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30019605/set-values-in-numpy-array-to-nan-by-index)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, I would recommend indexing using a boolean mask with the same shape as `arr1`. Integer array advanced indexing like in your previous question is a lot harder here because for each model x lat x lon, a variable number of elements need to be indexed. Example:

```
import numpy as np

arr1 = np.random.rand(*(100, 8, 96, 192))
arr2 = np.random.randint(low=0, high=80,size=(8, 96, 192))

# These are the possible indices along the first axis in arr1
# Hence shape (100, 1, 1, 1):
idx = np.arange(100)[:, None, None, None]

arr1[idx > arr2] = np.nan
```